# how to deduce template parameters for the end regex_token_iterator on the begin one?

Tags: c++, c++17

How to write the following so-called mini-reproducable example in which the begin iterator may be constract either on the base of `std::string_view` or `std::string`.

So, let's say that we have the following programme:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>
#include <iterator>
#include <string_view>

int main() {
  std::string_view sv("QWERTY");
  std::string str("QWERTY");
  std::regex rx(R"([\w])");
  for (auto it = std::regex_token_iterator(str.cbegin(), str.cend(), rx, 0); it != std::sregex_token_iterator(); it++) {
    std::cout << *it << std::endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

I wonder, how to specify the last `std::regex_token_iterator<???>()` on the base of the type of `it` in order not to be forced to change the code depending on whether `it` runs over `std::string_view` or `std::string`.

I have tried to specify like `decltype(it)::value_type` but I have got an error that there is no such a member type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're thinking way too deeply. You don't need the template parameters; the type you're trying to test against is the same type as `it`. So just use that:

```
it != decltype(it)()
```

Comment: Well, thanks ... that was a box that opened of itself .... Much as .... Having said that ... Why `std::iterator_traits<...>` does not contain `value_type` and `pointer` ? How is it imaginable?

Comment: @dronte7 It does. `std::regex_token_iterator<T>::value_type` is `std::sub_match<T>`. It's just not the type you need.

Comment: @rustyx, than what does this mean?
`no type named ‘value_type’ in ‘struct std::iterator_traits<std::__cxx11::sub_match<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > > >’
   12 |   for (auto it = std::regex_token_iterator(str.cbegin(), str.cend(), rx, 0); it != std::regex_token_iterator<decltype(it)::value_type>(); it++) {
`

Comment: @dronte7: To get the value_type of an iterator, you invoke `iterator_traits<iterator_type>::value_type`. You're not *using* the traits class.